# How to connect mysql using PHP executing from command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line

When I try to connect mysql using PHP and executing from Command Line using `php -f filename.php`, it throws "`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in ....`"

It perfectly works fine if I execute it from browser.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");

$test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $test_query);

$tblCnt = 0;
while($tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $tblCnt++;
  #echo $tbl[0]."<br />\n";
}

if (!$tblCnt) {
  echo "There are no tables<br />\n";
} else {
  echo "There are $tblCnt tables<br />\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, we need to provide UNIX socket:

```
mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, NULL, '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock') or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
```